# Targeting categories in custom fields

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, taxonomy, categories

I was hoping somebody could help me out with custom fields.

I created a custom post type called game-type in WordPress. In this I have the categories "Android", "iOS" and "PC", then within these I have categories for types of games "3D Action", "Classics", "Platform" etc.

So an example hierarchy for each post works like this:
Games > Android > 3D Action > Post (Game)

So far I've managed to call a list of categories using the code:

`

```
$taxonomy     = 'game-type';
$orderby      = 'name';
$show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$title        = '';

$args = array(
 'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
 'orderby'      => $orderby,
 'show_count'   => $show_count,
 'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
 'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
 'title_li'     => $title
);
?>

<ul>
<?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
</ul>`
```

But this lists all the categories in my custom field. Is there a way to target just the categories in "android"?

Your help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Site: http://www.sugartree.org.uk/company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [include/exclude](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Include_or_Exclude_Categories)?

```
$taxonomy     = 'game-type';...
$include      = 'ANDROID ID IE: 1'

    $args = array(...
        include           => $include
    );
```

**EDIT:** vancoder is right: it should be...

```
   $taxonomy     = 'game-type';...
    $child_of= 'ANDROID ID IE: 1'

        $args = array(...
            child_of    => $child_of
    );
```

Where $child_of is the ID of your subcategory.

Comment: Brandon = the include seems to be getting somewhere but it's cutting out the child categories and just leaving a link to Android.  I may have written it wrong, I've put:

 $include      = '4&post_type=games';...
  'include'      => $include,

Comment: @user27833 user ` for code or edit original question. You also may need a mixture of mine and vancoder's solution. (PS. it's Bandon)

Comment: I've tried

$child_of     = '4&post_type=games'; and $child_of     = 'ANDROID ID IE: 1';

They both deliver 'No categories' am I writing the ID wrong?

Comment: Maybe, It should be the ID of the Android category. It looks like you have missing quotes. meaning it should be `child_of = 4&taxonomy=game-type` `post_type` is not allowed as an accepted argument of `wp_list_categories`

Comment: That's still delivering 'no categories' the full ID from looking at categories (which is how i'd usually find the ID is : /edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=game-type&tag_ID=4&post_type=games

Comment: I created a chat room for this question let's talk about it there: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/7623/wordpress-stack-exchange-87836?tab=general Just saw you need 20 rep to do that though.

Comment: Has anybody got any more ideas for this?  I can't join the rooms

Comment: @user27833 The code is good. It's either a problem with how you are getting the category ID wrong or using the above code wrong. Unfortunately I can't tell you which.

Comment: OK thanks a lot for your help, at least I have something to build on now.  I'll keep experimenting.

Comment: I solved it.  I just need the number from the ID, that's it:
$child_of     = '4';

Comment: That's what i was _trying_ to say :) Will you accept  an answer? so this can be marked as answered?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
child_of => [id for android]
```

to your args.

Comment: Would I write it like this?

'child_of'  => [4&post_type=games],

It's not sending me anything back.

Comment: Please see example below.

Comment: I solved it. I just need the number from the ID, that's it: $child_of = '4'